# Automatically authenticate to my company's proxy without user interaction

Tags: windows, proxy

In my company there is a proxy that requires credentials.

I use Windows XP and I want to apply an indirection layer in my tcp/ip stack that makes this completely transparent.

For example it would be nice a **software that I can configure with my company proxy and act as I don't have any proxy in my network**.

With this software I don't have to configure software that don't consider my default proxy settings done with Internet Explorer.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Is the authentication the problem, or configuring each PC? I have a few ideas, but I don't know what the main problem is with your current setup that you need solved.

Comment: I'm using last.fm software but it fails when I give proxy's credentials. Perhaps the only way is to configure my computer to hide the needing of a proxy

Comment: Or perhaps.... report a bug to last.fm? Are you also sure that last.fm is not being blocked by the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Setup a proxy server on your local machine (such as squid).

Configure this proxy server to use your company proxy as an upstream proxy and give Squid your logon credentials. Unfortunately, this means putting your username/password into a file for Squid to use.

Also configure the proxy server to only accept requests from localhost.

Now, configure your browser/apps to use your local machine as the proxy.

Comment: it works! but it's not transparent, I need to configure my app

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you're looking for a proxy that'll allow NTLM authentication, and also require per-user authentication for auditing purposes.

Using a proxy that allows domained NTLM authentication would provide a seamless proxy environment for your IE users. The stumbling point is that you really need everyone in a domain, otherwise the authentication problem gets a lot worse. As it happens Squid, the product mentioned several times already, can do NTLM authentication if you set it up right.

The google term "squid ntlm" brings up several good pages describing how to set it up.

Comment: I don't think this relates to the poster's problem, since he says he's already got a proxy in place, but you won't be able to use Squid in transparent mode w/ authentication. The browser gets confused and things don't work right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Squid as a transparent proxy](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of proxy does your company use? If you don't know, just tell me how you configure it in your browser.

I highly doubt that this is really what you are looking for; most of your network traffic--including local network traffic--should not be routed through a proxy, and would have no relevance if it were.

It sounds like what you are looking for is a way to route all traffic through another computer; if this is the case, your company could set up a VPN connection for you through another machine or even a switch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use squid but it would be overkill just to supply one extra authentication header to parent proxy. Search for

```
aps098
```

on google and you will find what you need.